# How can I prevent links in iframes from opening in new window?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider this simple link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:{return false;}">Do Nothing</a>
```

When this is in the main document in a window, clicking it does nothing, because the `return false` cancels the click.

But when this is in an `iframe` document (in Firefox and Chrome at least), it opens a new tab window.

This is very annoying because I want to be able to hook a click event (in actuality using jQuery's `$(element).click(handler))`), do some logic, cancel the navigation, and **NOT** have that extra tab.

What's going on here and how can I stop this behavior?

Comment: if you're using `$(el).click(...)`, I assume you've checked that  your markup exists before you try to attach event listeners to it, and that the selector you're using is returning the elements you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, I have verified all of that. The issue seems to be in the browser, because I'm not even using jQuery in my example above and I still observe this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had an unrelated jQuery `click` event that was causing this behavior, so this was my user error. Dumb.

Comment: There's no way to derive this answer from the information you supplied in the question. You would probably be better off just deleting the question instead.

Comment: Agreed that there would be no way to guess what the problem was, but it might still be useful to future readers to be reminded to check for their own click handlers when trying to debug a problem like this.